# regex with special characters?

Tags: php, regex

i am looking for a regex that can contain special chracters like `/ \ . ' "`

in short i would like a regex that can match the following:

- may contain lowercase
- may contain uppercase
- may contain a number
- may contain space
- may contain `/ \ . ' "`

i am making a php script to check if a certain string have the above or not, like a validation check.

Comment: Validation check for what? Mysql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regular expression you are looking for is

```
^[a-z A-Z0-9\/\\.'"]+$
```

Remember if you are using PHP you need to use \ to escape the backslashes and the quotation mark you use to encapsulate the string.

In PHP using preg_match it should look like this:

```
preg_match("/^[a-z A-Z0-9\\/\\\\.'\"]+$/",$value);
```

This is a good place to find the regular expressions you might want to use.
http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can always escape them by appending a `\` in front of the special characters.

Comment: Except in a character class. And the \ itself is a special case that should be written as \\\\ to be escaped in the PHP string *and* in the regex.

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about language agnostic pcre's, what you do in your own language to output that slash is your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
preg_match("/[A-Za-z0-9\/\\.'\"]/", ...)
```

Comment: I would surround that with `^` and `$` and add a `+` before the end so it loops. The way it's written now it checks only one character before deciding that it matches.

Comment: The dot needs no escaping in the character class. But the backslash needs moar. Also the single quote needs no backslash when the PHP string is based on double quotes.

Comment: @Blindy You don't need those, if you check if only one character exists, so if this is true than input is invalid. If I put `^[...]+$` then if input match then it's valid. Both will do the same. @mario good to know about the dot in `[]`, and I remove unnecessary slashes

Answer (score 2):

NikoRoberts is 100% correct.
I would only add the following suggestion: When creating a PHP regex pattern string, always use: *single-quotes*. There are far fewer chars which need to be escaped (i.e. only the single quote and the backslash itself needs to be escaped (and the backslash only needs to be escaped if it appears at the end of the string)).

When dealing with *backslash soup*, it helps to print out the (interpreted) regex string. This shows you exactly what is being presented to the regex engine.

Also, a "number" might have an optional sign? Yes? Here is my solution (in the form of a tested script):

```php
<?php // test.php 20110311_1400
    $data_good = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDE'.
        'FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789+- /\\.\'"';
    $data_bad = 'abcABC012~!@##$%^&*()';

    $re = '%^[a-zA-Z0-9+\- /\\\\.\'"]*$%';
    echo($re ."\n");
    if (preg_match($re, $data_good)) {
        echo("CORRECT: Good data matches.\n");
    } else {
        echo("ERROR! Good data does NOT match.\n");
    }
    if (preg_match($re, $data_bad)) {
        echo("ERROR! Bad data matches.\n");
    } else {
        echo("CORRECT: Bad data does NOT match.\n");
    }
?>
```

Comment: p.s. jcubic's regex only checks one character and it fails to match a backslash. To match a backslash in the target string, there must be *four* (or *three*) backslashes in the regex pattern string.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will match a single character that fits the description you gave:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\ \\\/\.\'\"]
```

If your point is to insure that ONLY characters in this range of characters are used in your string, then you can use the negation of this which would be:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\ \\\/\.\'\"]
```

In the second case, you could use your regex to find the bad stuff (that you don't want to be included), and if it didn't find anything then your string pattern must be kosher, because I'm assuming that if you find one character that is not in the proper range, then your string is not valid.

so to put it in PHP syntax:

```
$regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\ \\\/\.\'\"]"

if preg_match( $regex, ... ) {
    // handle the bad stuff
}
```

Edit 1:
I've completely ignored the fact that backslashes are special in php double-quoted strings, so here is a correcting to the above code:

```
$regex = "[^a-zA-Z0-9\\ \\\\\\/\\.\\'\\\"]"
```

If that doesn't work it shouldn't take too much for someone to debug how many of the backslashes need to be escaped with a backslash, and what other characters need also to be escaped....